# rc.exe from windows sdk missing

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sdk

While doing some cleaning and reinstalling on my machine, I obviously cleaned one too many, and now I'm missing a rc.exe that's supposed to go either in my Visual Studio directory (not sure which one) or in my Microsoft SDKs directory.

The problem is that I don't want to reinstall the whole OS again, and that rc.exe is part of some SDK freely downloadable from Microsoft (apparently 6.0a version). I can't find it nevertheless.

***Anyone knows what rc.exe is part of, and what I need to download (and from where) to get it back ?***

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the Windows SDK - [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381042(VS.85).aspx)

> The Microsoft Windows Resource Compiler (RC) is a tool used in building Windows-based applications. This overview describes how to create a resource-definition (script) file, how to compile your application's resources, and how to add compiled resources to your application.
>
> This tool is available in Visual Studio and the Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit (SDK).

You don't say which version of Windows you are using. The Windows 7 SDK is no longer available from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=47&p=2&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=e6e1c3df-a74f-4207-8586-711ebe331cdc&u=details.aspx%3ffamilyid%3dC17BA869-9671-4330-A63E-1FD44E0E2505%26displaylang%3den) as of 2017, but other versions are available:

- [Win 8.1  SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk)
- [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A55B6B43-E24F-4EA3-A93E-40C0EC4F68E5&displaylang=en) for Windows® Server 2003 SP1 indicates that it's compatible with XP:

> This edition of the SDK replaces the previous SDKs for Windows XP SP2 and Windows Server 2003 and can be used to develop applications for those platforms.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. XP SP2

Comment: I found some link I thought it might do. Didn't work. Will try that other one you just put. Hoping for the best. In any case, +1 for the effort.